# can we get Tab key action on click on a tag using javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

When we click on a tag tab key should press or can we get any key action using javascript or tab key.

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
$('a').click(function(e){
//press tab key
})})
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="text" />
<div>Tab Key <span>9</span> <a href="#">click</a></div>
</body>
```

Comment: please elaborate a bit

Comment: He wants to send a keypress to the browser.  The example he's giving is a link that sends a tab keypress when you click it.